# Вычитание векторов в полярной системе координат

Tags: математика, геометрия

Есть два вектора A и B, заданные длиной и углом (от 0 до 360 градусов). Нужно найти угол вектора C, который получился в результате разницы векторов A и B.

Я пытался. Но уверен что это принципиально неверно.

```
Vector Computing::lateralDem(Vector v1, Vector v2) {
    double z = pow(v1.value, 2) + pow(v2.value, 2) - 2 * v1.value*v2.value*cos(v1.angle + PI - v2.angle); // --длина(по теореме косинусов)
    double c = asin(sin(v1.angle + PI - v2.angle) * v2.value / z) - v1.angle; // --угол(по теореме синусов)
    return{ c,sqrt(z) };
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Vector Computing::Subtract(Vector v1, Vector v2) {
  // calculates new vector as (v2 - v1)

  double a1 = v1.angle * PI / 180;
  double a2 = v2.angle * PI / 180;

  double x1 = v1.value * cos(a1);
  double y1 = v1.value * sin(a1);
  double x2 = v2.value * cos(a2);
  double y2 = v2.value * sin(a2);

  double x3 = x2 - x1;
  double y3 = y2 - y1;

  double value3 = sqrt(x3*x3 + y3*y3);
  double angle3 = atan2(y3, x3);

  return { value = value3, angle = angle3 / PI * 180 };
}
```

Павел, прошу прощения, я погорячился и был неправ. Разность двух векторов это вектор, соединяющий их концы - направленный от конца "вычитаемого" к концу "уменьшаемого". То есть в Вашем последнем примере

```
v1 = { 0, 100 };
v2 = { 180, 100 };

v3 = v2 - v1 = { 180, 200 };
```

Что касается отрицательных углов, диапазон значений, возвращаемых функцией `atan2`, - от `-PI` до `PI`. Если Вам нужны значения от нуля до `2PI`, просто прибавьте `PI` к отрицательному результату.

Comment: Я бы воспользовался [`atan2`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/atan2) - эта функция автоматически находит нужный квадрант.

Comment: @Harry да, спасибо, согласен. и прямой угол заодно будет учтен.

Comment: Почему-то угол всегда равен 0

Comment: @PavelSaenko Это Вы неаккуратно код скопировали :). Покажите исходные вектора.

Comment: @PavelSaenko *я надеюсь, вы помните о том, что тригонометрические функции считают в радианах, а не в градусах?*

Comment: @Igor ну например вот так `lateralDem({ 60, 90 }, { 270, 100 });`

Comment: @PavelSaenko Та-а-ак. Значит, не помните.

Comment: @PavelSaenko А смело Вы градусы с радианами складываете. `v1.angle * PI / 180`

Comment: @igor Я перевел градусы в радианы и затем снова в градусы но ответ при тех же входным параметрах получился странным, а именно:  минус 102 градуса и 183 значение. Переводил след. образом `double angle1 = (v1.angle * (PI / 180));`  и `  double angle3 =( atan2(y3, x3)) * 180 / PI;` соответсвенно

Comment: @PavelSaenko Хорошо. Что Вам кажется странным в этом результате? Какой результат Вы ожидали?

Comment: @igor Диапазон лежит от 0 до 360 градусов и не может быть отрицательным. А также величина получилась больше чем до вычитания

Comment: @PavelSaenko Вы представляете себе график арктангенса? Что в `{ 60, 90 }` является углом, а что длиной?

Comment: @igor первое значение - угол в градусах,  второе  -значение. Я пробовал {0,100} и {180, 100} - т.е. два противоположно направленных вектора одинаковой длинны и разность их длинн должна равняться 0. Но функция почему-то возвращает 200.

Comment: @PavelSaenko разность должна равняться нулю только для одинаковых векторов. А у вас они разные, **очень** разные (аж противоположные!). Потому и разность большая выходит.

Comment: См. https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPOPF.jpg ваши вектора - синий (А) и оранжевый (В). Зеленый - разность А-В.

Answer (score 7):

Переход в декартову систему, вычитание, переход в полярную

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Думаю, далее понятно, как посчитать угол?